# emacs truncate mode for specific buffers?

Tags: emacs

In my ~/.emacs, I have

```
(global-visual-line-mode t)
```

However, this is making buffer-list hard to read if the emacs window is and narrow. How I can I set it up so I can have buffer-list (and potentially other buffers) to truncate mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most modes have a hook that runs when the mode is set, usually named on the form `...-mode-hook`. You could add to a modes' hook to truncate lines (effectively turning off `visual-line-mode`):

```lisp
(add-hook
 'some-mode-hook
 '(lambda ()
    (toggle-truncate-lines 1)
    )
 )
```

Comment: After a bit of research, it seems `Buffer-menu-mode-hook` is the hook run by Buffer menu mode, the mode used in the buffer list.

Comment: Note that if a mode is defined with the standard macros, the hook *will* exist and be run (and modes defined in other ways generally still take care of this). So mostly you can use `M-: major-mode RET` to get the mode name, and then append `-hook` to that name.

Comment: I feel as if I have more control using `(setq truncate-lines t)` and `(setq truncate-lines nil)` for specific buffers when doing something programmatically.  It has always been a little difficult for my brain to think of this variable as a function, but I'm not sure why that is.

Answer (score 0):

It's worked form me, whit speedbar-mode:

```
(add-hook
 'speedbar-mode-hook
 '(lambda ()
    (visual-line-mode 0) ; disable only in the buffer sr-speedbar
    )
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in markdown mode, so it's always in truncate mode when I'm working with markdown files.  (Tested in Emacs v28.1)

```lisp
    ;; init.el
    (add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook (lambda () (setq truncate-lines t)))
```